# json-rpc malformed request with &nbsp;

Tags: json, html-parsing, django-views

I'm building an application that communicates with a django backend using json-rpc. So far all has been working well. However I've found an anomaly in sending " ". As far as I know the request works fine, however django interprets the response badly. I've reproduced a simplified request and response below:

Request:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"1","method":"test","params":
{"id":"80","name":"tests","introduction":"hello &nbsp;there"}}
```

Django receives:

```
<QueryDict:u'{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"1","method":"test","params":
{"id":"80","name":"tests","introduction":"hello ': [u''], u'nbsp': [u''], u'there"}}': [u'']}>
```

Expected response:

```
<QueryDict: {u'{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"1","method":"test","params":
{"id":"80","name":"tests","introduction":"hello &nbsp;there"}}': [u'']}>
```

It seems like django interprets the & and the ; as special characters and so creates an unexpected dictionary in its request.POST variable.

What do I need to do to make sure that the json string doesn't get malformed? I have tried encoding it using the php htmlspecialchars() method, but since that doesn't remove the '&' the problem persists.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Workaround: if it's just the nbsp, then use a raw UTF-8 character there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've tried that, but I think that django converts the characters before I get a chance. So far I've just removed the spaces manually, which works for me for now.

Comment: default charset is UTF-8, unless you specify something else in settings. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#default-charset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django is handling the (POST?) request by decoding the body (your json string) as if it were a query string, and *not* a json.

Within a query string, `&` and `;` denote the end of a key:value pair. Splitting up your request body on those two characters yields the key:value pairs you see in the Django QueryDict.

You need to get hold of the POST request body and explicitly decode it to a dict yourself using either the standard lib json, or simplejson module.

I have little experience with Django specifically, but I imagine that somewhere in your view handler you would do something akin to:

```
try:
    data = json.loads(requesst.raw_post_data)
    ## work with the data...
except ValueError:
    ## do something...
```

No doubt Django provides a way to move this json handling out of your views, and to somewhere more suitable.

Comment: Great. request.raw_post_data is exactly what I needed.